# openshift pod - Ready state shows False

Tags: openshift, redhat, kubernetes-helm

When i run the below oc command:

`oc describe mypod`

i see the below status under Conditions section:

```
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True 
  Ready             False 
  ContainersReady   True 
  PodScheduled      True
```

What could cause the Ready to be shown as False?

The pod is up and running for more than a month.

I could also see in the service to which this pod is associated, there is a X mark under receiving traffic column. (i think this means this pod is not taking traffic)

Comment: You should be able to use `oc get pod mypod -o yaml`, `oc get events`, and `oc logs mypods` to try to further diagnose any issues preventing your pod from becoming `Ready`.

Comment: Is there a readinessCheck failing?

Comment: The actuator/info endpoint is not returning success. The pod is up though. No sign of any failures under the pods Events tab